# Calculate Sum and Insert as Row

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

Using SSIS I am bringing in raw text files that contain this in the output:

[image: Current Output]

I use this data later to report on. The Key columns get pivoted. However, I don't want to show all those columns individually, I only want to show the total. 
To accomplish this my idea was calculate the Sum on insert using a trigger, and then insert the sum as a new row into the data.

The output would look something like:

[image: Needed Output]

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Is there a better way to do this dynamically on pivot? To be clear I'm not just pivoting these rows for a report, there are other ones that don't need the sum calculated.

Comment: Hi. Why do you think this has something to do with normalization? Also, what are you able to do? PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Also see [mcve].

Comment: You are correct normalization should not be a tag here. I listed  what I am currently able to do and what I need to get done. I dont see any issue with me posting an image here to provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using derived column and Script Component

You can achieve this by following these steps:

1. Add a derived column (name: `intValue`) with the following expression:

   ```
   (DT_I4)(RIGHT([Value],2) == "GB" ? SUBSTRING([Value],1,FINDSTRING( [Value], " ", 1)) : "0")
   ```

   So if the value ends with `GB` then the number is taken else the result is `0`.
2. After that add a script component, in the Input and Output Properties, click on the Output and set the `SynchronousInput` property to `None`
3. Add 2 Output Columns `outKey` , `outValue`

[image]

4. In the Script Editor write the following script *(VB.NET)*

   ```
   Private SumValues As Integer = 0
   Public Overrides Sub PostExecute()
       MyBase.PostExecute()

       Output0Buffer.AddRow()
       Output0Buffer.outKey = ""
       Output0Buffer.outValue = SumValues.ToString & " GB"

   End Sub

   Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

       Output0Buffer.AddRow()
       Output0Buffer.outKey = Row.Key
       Output0Buffer.outValue = Row.Value
       SumValues += Row.intValue

   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to show you a way but I don't recommend adding total to the end of the detail data. If you are going to report on it show it as a total.

After source add a data transformation:

C#

1. Add two columns to your data flow: Size int and type string
2. Select Value as readonly

Here is the code:

```
string[] splits = Row.value.ToString().Split(' '); //Make sure single quote for char
int goodValue;

if(Int32.TryParse(splits[0], out goodValue))
{
   Row.Size = goodValue;
   Row.Type = "GB";
}
else
{
   Row.Size = 0;
   Row.Type="None";
}
```

Now you have the data with the proper data types to do arithmatic in your table.

If you really want the data in your format. Add a multicast and an aggregate and SUM(Size) and then merge back into your original flow.

Comment: I think it is easier and faster to achieve this using a script component rather than adding multicast, aggregate and merging, check my answer. *i used VB.NET again :)*

Comment: It would for me to do in a report since the columns are pivoted dynamically, making it hard for me to do calculations

Comment: I wouldn't even recommend the summary but carry the details and then aggregate in the report

Comment: What do you mean carry the details? And what do you mean by not recommending summary? Could you give an example?

Comment: I would have 3 columns stored in db. Device name, size,  type for each row. I would then create a report that displayed that info and then put a total on the end that sums size.

Comment: It's a bad idea to store details and summary in one table

Comment: Currently the table has similar three columns: Serial Number, Key, Value. When I create a report, it pivots and makes the key the columns. Why would I split these up into more tables? Again my report shows more than just these memory sizes, so its hard for me to do the calculations dynamically unless theres an easier way, hence me putting in the data ahead of time.

Comment: I am using SSRS for reporting btw

Comment: The problem that both @Hadi and I identified and solved is that you have a text column that needs aggregation on the values that actually have numbers in them. We both found out a way to split them (I used split and he used a derived column). Now that you have a column that has totally numeric and is actually a numeric you should be able to do any arithmatic that you want to do. If you have a separate SSRS question, then I suggest you post that.

Comment: @AlanPear i think that your question is not related to ssis. I think you should ask a new question tagged with ssrs and you must provide all details (that you have given in comments)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem in another way using a trigger.

I used this code:

```
INSERT INTO [Table] (
[Filename]
, [Type]
, [DeviceSN]
, [Property]
, [Value]   
)
SELECT ms.[Filename],
ms.[Type],
ms.[DeviceSN],
'Memory Device.Total' AS [Key],
CAST(SUM(CAST(left(ms.[Value], 2) as INT)) AS VARCHAR) + ' GB' as 'Value'
FROM [Table] ms
JOIN inserted i ON i.Row# = ms.Row#
WHERE ms.[Value] like '%GB'
GROUP BY ms.[filename],
ms.[type],
ms.[devicesn]
```